# Shiny Widget Value based off other Widget

Tags: r, shiny, widget

So Lets say that I have the following R shiny App UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("x1",
                     "Choose knot 1:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = # here I want the value of slider x2
                     value = 10, # default value
                     step=0.01),
         sliderInput("x2",
                     "Choose knot 2:",
                     min = # here I want value of slider input x1
                     max = 50,
                     value = 25, # default value
                     step=0.01),
      )
   )
)
```

I want the max value of slider input x1 to be the current value of slider input x2, and I want the min value of slider input x2 to the current value of slider input x1. How do I get the current value from a slider input within another widget?

Comment: What do you mean by widget? The different `sliderInput`s?

Comment: @starja, yes  ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `updateSliderInput` inside an `observe` within `server` to get the desired behavior.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateSliderInput(session, inputId = "x1", max = input$x2)
    updateSliderInput(session, inputId = "x2", min = input$x1)
  })
}
```